# How to read content of file and set it to a variable using bash shell within dockerfile?

Tags: bash, shell-script, docker

I need to read content of the `credential` file into the variable `MYPASS` (can be defined also as an ENV), then printing out it calling `echo` within my Dockerfile. I tried a lot of ways, but couldn't solve this issue yet. So the last version of code looks like following:

```
FROM ubuntu

RUN mkdir /asset

WORKDIR /asset

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install bc -yy

RUN touch credential
RUN echo 'admin12345' > credential

RUN export MYPASS=`echo ${cat ./credential} | bc -l`
RUN echo $MYPASS
```

Any idea ? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/29110#issuecomment-453718228

It's some ugly, but works.

Comment: seems not working..anyway i moved getting credential from Dockerfile and putted it into my task.sh script in order to make stuffs more secure, since storing sensitive data in docker image is not recommended